# Spring Webflux endpoint working as a topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I have an Flux endpoint that I provide to clients (subscribers) to receive updated prices. I'm testing it accessing the URL (http://localhost:8080/prices) though the browser and it works fine. The problem I'm facing (I'm maybe missing some concepts here) is when I open this URL in many browsers and I expect to receive the notification in all of them, but just one receives. It is working as a queue instead of a topic (like in message Brokers). Is that correct behavior?

```
@GetMapping(value = "prices", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<Collection<Price>>> prices() {
return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .map(sec -> pricesQueue.get())
        .filter(prices -> !prices.isEmpty())
        .map(prices -> ServerSentEvent.<Collection<Price>> builder()
                .event("status-changed")
                .data(prices)
                .build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`get` isn't a standard queue operation, but this is almost certainly because your `pricesQueue.get()` method *isn't* idempotent. With every request (with every browser window you open in this case), you'll get a new flux that calls `pricesQueue.get()` every 5 seconds. Now if `pricesQueue.get()` just retrieves the latest item in the queue and does nothing with it, all is good - all your subscribers receive the same item, and the same item is displayed. But if it acts more like a `poll()` where it *removes* the item in the queue after it's retrieved it, then only the first flux will get that value - the rest won't, as by that point it will have been removed.

You've really two main options here:

- Change your `get()` implementation (or implement a new method) so that it doesn't mutate the queue, only retrieves a value.
- Turn the flux into a hot flux. Store `Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).map(sec -> pricesQueue.get()).publish().autoConnect()` somewhere as a field (let's say as `queueFlux`), then just return `queueFlux.filter(prices -> !prices.isEmpty()).map(...)` in your controller method.

Comment: yes, you are right bout the get(), it behaves like poll(), although I don't think this is the concept I'm missing here. The behavior I would like to have is the same as using SseEmiter class, where only current subscribers would receive a notification (all of them).

Comment: changing get() implementation to keep values for further subscribers is not the desirable behavior and it also would make subscribers to receive the same notification more than once.

Comment: Turn the flux into a hot flux is nice (thanks for that) but it also makes further subscribers to receive values. As I said I just want tthe current subscribers to get notification at a certain moment.

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException In that case, try using `publish()` instead of `replay()`?

Comment: it kind of worked. The problem I'm facing is: 3 subscribers waiting for prices, price-1 arrives and only subscriber-1 receives it, then price-2 arrives and  subscriber-1 and  subscriber-2 receive it, then price-3 arrives and all 3 subscribers receive it, from that point on everything works like a charm. Any idea?